# How to resize and reposition PaperJs drawing with canvas size change?

Tags: paperjs

I'm creating an application using Paperjs to drawing some sketch on an image, persisting the sketch without the background and display back the sketch along with background image.

In my Paperjs canvas, I have a raster image and on top of that I'm making some sketch pointing a part of the background image. After the drawing is done, I'm doing JSON export, excluding background raster image, to persist the drawing. Now when I export it back, the background raster image is generated dynamically and the Paper canvas size is set to the size of the image. But if the browser window size is different then the size of the image will be different than where the original drawing is created.

The issue that I'm facing if the image size isn't the used while creating the sketch, its pointing to the different part of the image. Is there any way we can proportionally change the paperjs drawing so that the sketch points to the same point of the background raster image?

Any help would be appreciated.

Below is an example :

With actual size -

[image]

After resize

[image]

Comment: Could you provide a reproduction code so that we can help you better ?

Comment: You can store the position of your sketch relative to the top left corner (or the center, or any point) of the background image. Then it will be easy to reposition it from the background image position after a resize.

Comment: Thanks @arthur.sw, I think that would solve my issue. Do you have a sample code snippet for storing the sketch relative to the center of background image?

Comment: save `relativeOffset = sketch.position.subtract(background.position)`, and restore with `sketch.position = background.position.add(relativeOffset)`

Comment: you might want to store the scaling difference of the background in consideration: save `originalBackgroundSize = background.bounds.size` and restore with `sketch.position = background.position.add(relativeOffset.multiply(background.size.divide(originalBackgroundSize)))`

Comment: Thanks @arthur.sw. Actually I'm using exportJSON and importJSON to save and redraw my whole sketch. The method you describe, can this be applied to the whole exported sketch at one go or we have do this for each element individually? We will have multiple items drawn on top of background image. When the canvas size changes, raster with position: view.center fits into the whole view but imported drawing doesn't scale & positioned appropriately

Comment: @arthur.sw - any thought?

Comment: I guess you could do it just once for all objects (since all objects will be scaled with the same proportions).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm able to achieve what I wanted to with the below changes. Thanks @arthur.sw for your help.
Here originalViewSize is the original size on which the actual sketch was created.

**Steps:**

- Update view size
- Calculate x-axis and y-axis scale factor
- Update bounds for background image
- Update active layer positions
- Scale active layer

*// Changing view size and calculating scale factor for x & y-axis*

```
paperScope.view.viewSize = new Size(originalViewSize.width + 200, originalViewSize.height + 100);
const xScale = paperScope.view.viewSize.width /originalViewSize.width;
const yScale = paperScope.view.viewSize.height /originalViewSize.height;
```

*// Update  b/g image bounds*

```
backgroundRaster.bounds = paperScope.view.bounds;
paperScope.project.activeLayer.position.x = paperScope.project.activeLayer.position.x * xScale;
paperScope.project.activeLayer.position.y = paperScope.project.activeLayer.position.y * yScale;
paperScope.project.activeLayer.scale(xScale, yScale);
```

Comment: I am facing similar issue. Quick question - if the new size is changing only in only one dimension, wouldnt that distort your shape? If you had a square 20x20, and new canvas size doubles just the width but not height, your square would become 40x20, making it a rectangle. Were you able to fix this somehow?

Comment: Thats true, we have actually decided to use fix size canvas and have an option to resize to using multipliers

Comment: What is "backgroundRaster"? Is it a single background image? What should I do if I have dozens of raster images that are dynamically inserted by the user? How to update the bounds of all the layers in canvas?